# Installshield Run EXE then wait for completion before running another

Tags: executable, installshield, exe

I am using Installshield, and have had success in launching my exe install files (such as KLite) after all my files have transferred to their target destination.

My question is this:

I am currently able to launch all the install exe's necessary, but they all launch at the same time, which can be rather annoying and cluttering. I am using a "Custom Action" to launch each executable. I am trying different "In-Script Execution" properties to no avail. My "Return Processing" is set to Asynchronous(Waits for exit code), yet it still is giving me problems.

I'd like to have each one execute once the previous is completed.

Anyone have experience in this? It has to be possible...

Thanks,
-Kyle

Comment: asynchronous isn't wait for exit, it is run all at once. try synchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want Sync not ASync.  BTW, I don't reccomend EXE CA's except in the rarest of situations.  Primarily because they are out of process with very limited ability to report back success and 0 ability to write back to the Windows Installer Log and have very unprofessional flashing of DOS CMD windows.

Always try to use C++ / C# custom actions instead.

Also be sure to read the following:

**Integration Hurdles for EXE Custom Actions** 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2007/10/20/integration-hurdles-for-exe-custom-actions.aspx

If you must use an EXE be sure to use something like WiX QuiteCA ( you can wrap this up into a WiX merge module and consume it with your InstallShield Basic MSI project ) to help shield you from these problems and get improved logging.

Comment: The Sync call worked.

I am using the Installshield custom action to launch the executable. Do you know of another way to perform this to avoid said problems?

I could not find any references to the WiX QuiteCA solution.. .

I currently copy over all files, then run the exe's for them so that the user can install them.

I would like to bypass the problems you mentioned. For one example, I run the exe, and after the install is complete, the user must hit "enter" on the DOS prompt to continue. This is unacceptable to me, and I would like to see about bypassing this...

Comment: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm

The ideal solution is to get rid of calling the EXE's.  What are they doing?  It is likely you could have InstallShield / MSI do what they are doing and that you are creating what some call a "Trojan MSI" ( that is it looks like an install but it really isn't ).

Comment: I am using a "silent install" instead, which looks much nicer than before. I am currently using a Custom Action to call an exe in silent mode.